Sending a polars dataframe via email
I am looking for a way to send a pl.DataFrame via email. The email should practically show the result of print(df). What would be best practice here?
I have already tried to convert the DataFrame to HTML using great_tables.as_raw_html(), but when sending it using Python's smtplib library I get an error that looks something like this:
An error occurred while sending the trade signals email: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 49-123: ordinal not in range(128)

This question is similar to: The smtplib.server.sendmail function in python raises UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The answers in the question didn't really help. Encoding toutf-8 didn't do the trick. What I figured out is that using pl.Config.set_tbl_formatting('NOTHING') is helpful. Also, making sure that the content of the dataframe has no special characters helps. In my case, I think the & in some cells caused some issues. I was then able to send the pl.DataFrame without converting it to a greater_tables-object.
